# Using Gram-Schmidt to find Orthonomal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$f(x)=−3, g(x)=−9x+6$  and  $h(x)=3x^{2},
\langle p,q \rangle =\int_0^1 p(x)q(x)dx$

Use the Gram-Schmidt process to determine an orthonormal basis for the subspace
spanned by the functions $f(x), g(x)$, and $h(x)$. 
I've obtained the first base to be $-1$ but got the 2nd base to be $-9x+\frac{9}{2}$
But this was incorrect?
Any help on the 2nd and 3rd base?

Comment: Please check if I formatted the 2nd base you got right. Did you mean $\frac{-9x + 9}{2}$ or $-9x + \frac92$?

Comment: Yes you formatted it correctly..Thanks!!

Comment: You found an ortho**gonal** basis, whereas the question was to find an ortho**normal** one

Comment: If you multiply the functions and apply the framework-Schmidt procedure, it must be true but then check how you are determining the inner product of the two chosen functions say <for,g>

Comment: @Qwerty Do i have to normalise my base in that case?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: So i multiplied that out and got the basis to be 27/4 but that was also wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To find an orthonormal basis, the $2$nd base would be $${-9x+9/2\over||-9x+9/2|| }$$ where $$||-9x+9/2||^2 =\langle-9x+9/2,-9x+9/2\rangle=\int_0^1(-9x+9/2)^2dx$$